# break a string into 'first' and 'second'

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

I have read through countless `strtok` posts, even copied some directly in their entirety into a new `int main`, but I can't figure out how to create the functions `get_first` and `get_second`.

```
get_first("This is a sentence."); //returns "This"

get_rest("This is a sentence."); //returns "is"
```

This is what I have so far, I have had nothing but trouble with `strtok`, but I don't know what else to use.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * get_first(char * string) {
    string = strtok(string, " ");
    return string;
}

char * get_second(char * string) {
    string = strtok(string, " ");
    string = strtok(NULL, " ");
    return string;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char * test_string = "This is a sentence.";
    char * first = get_first(test_string);
    char * second = get_second(test_string);
    printf("%s\n", first);
    printf("%s\n", second);
}
```

Getting no faults compiling with gcc -g -Wall, but it always seg faults.  I think I have tried every permutation of `char c[]` and `char * c` there is.

Comment: Firstly, `strtok` modifies the string and hence it must be writeable. Your `test_string` is read only. Secondly, you cannot call `get_second` on the same string because it will no longer be the original string after the `get_first` call due to the modifications that `strtok` does to it.

Comment: `char test_string[] = ...`

Comment: @melpomene `get_second` does not work as expected after `get_first`.

Comment: Yes, I was largely confused around the specifics of `strtok`, I think I have a much better grasp on it now, thank you.

Comment: change this line: `string = strtok(NULL, " ");` to `string = string+strlen(string);`  or perhaps: ``string = string+strlen(string)+1;`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok` changes the string. (but String literals are not allowed to change.)
So  create a copy.

Do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * get_first(const char *string){
    char *clone = strdup(string);//create copy, strdup is non standard. malloc and copy.
    char *token = strtok(clone, " ");
    if(token)
        token = strdup(token);
    free(clone);
    return token;
}

char * get_second(const char *string) {
    char *clone = strdup(string);
    char *token = strtok(clone, " ");
    if(token && (token = strtok(NULL, " ")))
        token = strdup(token);
    free(clone);
    return token;
}

int main(void) {
    char * test_string = "This is a sentence.";
    char * first = get_first(test_string);
    char * second = get_second(test_string);
    printf("%s\n", first);
    printf("%s\n", second);
    free(first);
    free(second);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thank you.  I had tried copying the strings in a previous attempt, but I was using `strcpy` and kept getting seg faults every time I tried to print them.